# SWT on Mac OS X: Make program reappear when user clicks on dock icon

Tags: java, macos, swt

I have an SWT application running on Mac OS X. When the user clicks on the 'close' button of the shell, I ignore the close request and just hide the shell by calling Shell.setVisible(false).

Now, how do I make my program reappear when the user clicks on the dock icon? I've tried attaching various listeners to the shell, to no avail. Couldn't find anything helpful via Google either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This feature is shell independent, hence listeners to a shell don't work. Unfortunately, it looks like there is no such feature implemented yet in SWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of one of the [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) developers (it's [this message](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/smartgit/message/1162), but you need to join the group to see it) - they've logged a bug about this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358376